# Docker Python File Input Selector

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to configure a Docker image so that a user can type in "docker run image" and have a window pop up to select the input file. I tried to use Tkinter when creating the Docker image, but the Python script errors out when it tries to load Tkinter.

Since Tkinter did not work I tried to just switch to a normal input query using:

```
path= input('Input the file path:\n')
```

But now I am getting an "EOFError: EOF when reading a line" when it gets to the input() line.

My Dockerfile is as follows

```
FROM python:3
ADD script.py /
RUN pip install xlrd
RUN pip install numpy
RUN pip install matplotlib
CMD [ "python", "./script.py" ]
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening? I'm very new to using Docker so any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to run the container with `docker run -ti image` to make sure that it runs in interactive mode with the terminal attached.

Running X11 GUI applications is a bit more tricky since you need to give the container access to your display. [This blog post](http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/) describes the process in more details.

Comment: It allows input now, but it will not allow matplotlib to open a display for the plot.

Comment: @DLee I updated the answer with a link that should be helpful.

Comment: Run `xhost +` in the host and try adding: `-e DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix` to the `docker run`.